# ios 7 bottomLayoutGuide with uitabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios7, uitabbar

I am trying to anchor the bottom of a label to the top of a tabbar using `bottomLayoutGuide` introduced in ios7. it works initially when I run the app, but when I switch to the other tab and back again the label moves behind the translucent tabbar (gets anchored to the bottom of the view).

I added a log to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` inside one of the tab's viewcontroller and the value of `bottomLayoutGuide.length` is reset to 0 after the respective tab is switched back.

My viewcontroller is a child of `UITabBarController`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in ios7? This happen both in the simulator and device.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in iOS 7. Please file a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Interface Builder and storyboards: in the attributes inspector for the view controller, deselect 'Extend Edges - Under Bottom Bars'. I was having a similar problem and this worked for me.

Comment: This gives me around 8 px gap between tab bar and the view.